# Processing of kivy canvas texture in memory

Tags: python, image-processing, canvas, kivy

I want to pass pixels from the kivy canvas to keras model (neural network). Simple approach would be to export the image to png and then read it using scikit-image or PIL. Question is can this be done in memory without such redundant steps?

This is what I came up with:

```
fbo = Fbo()
fbo.add(self.canvas)
fbo.draw()
img = Image.frombytes('RGBA', img_size, fbo.pixels)
```

In order to check if everything works, `img` was saved as png. Unfortunately it turned out to be complete mess. My question is how can I get it to work properly?

Here is code that reproduces/demonstrates this problem:

```
from PIL import Image
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Line, Fbo
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class Painter(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y), width=50)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]

    def save(self, obj):

        fbo = Fbo()
        fbo.add(self.canvas)
        fbo.draw()
        img = Image.frombytes('RGBA', self.size, fbo.pixels)
        img.save('img.png')

class App(App):

    def build(self):
        layout = FloatLayout()
        painter = Painter()
        btn = Button(text='Save', on_release=painter.save, size_hint=(0.2,0.2))

        layout.add_widget(painter)
        layout.add_widget(btn)
        return layout

App().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Every kivy widget has a `export_to_png` method which allow to save a `png` image of the canvas of this widget so instead of using Fbo and PIL Image you could use it.

Something like this:

```
...

class Painter(Widget):

    ...

    def save(self, *args):
        self.export_to_png(filename='img')

    ...
...
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but it looks like sending a parcel to your flatmate through postal office instead of just handing in it yourself. This `export_to_png` method already transforms canvas into unsigned bytes. The problem is how to use them directly

Answer (score 0):

You can [read the source](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/widget.py#L607) to see how `Widget.export_to_png` works, then use a similar method yourself. Once you have the texture, probably you can get the pixel information you want from the [pixels attribute](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.texture.html#kivy.graphics.texture.Texture.pixels).

You can also replace the widget's canvas with an Fbo, to avoid the need to make a new one each time.